# Read an animated GIF pixel by pixel with JavaFX

Tags: image, javafx, animated-gif

I know how to load and display an animated GIF in a javafx window, but what I need is to read the GIF image frame by frame and pixel by pixel.
For example with PNG images, I use the PixelReader associated with the loaded Image and I can get the color of each pixel with the getColor(int x, int y) function with something like this :

```
PixelReader pixelReader = image.getPixelReader();
for (int line = 0; line < imageHeight; line++) {
    for (int column = 0; column < imageWidth; column++) {
                colors[column][line] = pixelReader.getColor(column, line));
    }
}
```

But if I try the same kind of thing with an animated GIF, getPixelReader() returns null. According to Java doc, it could be because the image is "*in a format that is not supported for reading and writing pixels to.*".

Does anyone have an other solution?

Comment: Maybe see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28183667/how-i-can-stop-an-animated-gif-in-javafx) (this references a third party library for reading animated gifs).

Comment: JavaFX doesn't have a public API to access pixels of GIFs, nor does standard Java as far as I know.  You need to either write the code yourself (not advised) or use a third-party library or code snippet to decode gif data.  You can search for third-party libraries by running a google search on "java gif decoder".